# Thymeleaf ['fragment' to 'replace' and dynamic 'fragments' from templates into 'fragment']

Tags: java, html, spring, popup, thymeleaf

[1/2 problem solved but you can look for that f*n pop-up window side 'Login' button]

The goal of this question is to implement fragments in both directions, allowing a template with MainTemplate to be used in main.html, bmi.html, etc., while also being able to send variable content from main.html, bmi.html, etc. into the MainTemplate within the mainTemplateElement fragment using replace or insert syntax.

In short, the MainTemplate fragment should be replaced with {template}.html, and the {template}.html fragment should be replaced (in small part) within MainTemplate (inside "mainTemplateElement").

one of templates file code:

```
type<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Noto+Sans"/>
    <title>Main</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div th:replace="~{fragments/mainTemplate :: mainTemplateElement}">
        <div th:fragment="contents" th:remove="tag">
            <div class="text-block">

                <H1>CONTENTS</H1>

                <a href="joinUs.html" class="joinUs-link">
                    <button class="joinUs-button">
                        <span class="button-text">JOIN US</span>
                    </button>
                </a>

            </div>
       </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And mainTemplate.html from 'fragments' package code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Noto+Sans"/>
    <title>Main Template</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div th:fragment="mainTemplateElement" th:remove="tag">
        <div class="container">
            <header class="header"></header>
            <nav class="menu">
                <div class="nav-left">
                    <a th:href="@{/main}" class="nav-button"><span class="button-text">MAIN</span></a>
                    <a th:href="@{/anotherFile}" class="nav-button"><span class="button-text">BMI</span></a>
                <div class="nav-right">
                    <button class="nav-button" onclick="openForm()">LOGIN</button>
                    <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
                        <form class="form-container">

                            <label><b>Email</b></label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

                            <label><b>Password</b></label>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

                            <div style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="form2Example3">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Example3">
                                        Remember me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <a href="#" class="forgot-password">Forgot password?</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn" style="margin-right: 10px;">Login</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center text-lg-start mt-4 pt-2">
                                <p class="small fw-bold mt-2 pt-1 mb-0">
                                    Don't have an account? <a href="#" style="color: darkred">Register</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>


<!--            <div th:replace="~{templates/main :: contents}"></div>-->

            <footer class="footer">
                <p>&copy;</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <div class="shader"></div>

        <script>
            function openForm() {
                var formPopup = document.getElementById("myForm");
                var shader = document.querySelector('.shader');
                formPopup.classList.add('active');
                shader.classList.add('active');
            }

            function closeForm() {
                var formPopup = document.getElementById("myForm");
                var shader = document.querySelector('.shader');
                formPopup.classList.remove('active');
                shader.classList.remove('active');
            }

            const formPopup = document.querySelector('.form-popup');
            const openFormButton = document.querySelector('.nav-button');
            const shader = document.querySelector('.shader');

            function handleClickOutsideForm(event) {
                if (!formPopup.contains(event.target) && event.target !== openFormButton) {
                    closeForm();
                }
            }

            document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutsideForm);
        </script>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

There. Oh. And after 12 hour of fighting with this what's above (!#*#**!*$ mother f...) my Login button pop-up window does not work... soooo. Yup. Can anybody help me?

popup CSS:

```
.form-popup {
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 3px solid #bba674;
    z-index: 10;
}
.form-popup.active {
    display: block;
}

.form-container {
    font-size: 20px;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}

.form-container input[type=text], .form-container input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
    border: none;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

.form-container input[type=text]:focus, .form-container input[type=password]:focus {
    background-color: #ddd;
    outline: none;
}

.form-container::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 9;
    display: none;
}

.form-container .btn {
    align-self: center;
    background-color: seagreen;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #bba674;
    padding: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.btn:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.form-container .cancel {
    background-color: darkred;
}

.form-container .btn:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.shader {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 8;
}

.form-popup.active {
    display: flex;
}

.shader.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out Thymeleaf Layout Dialect? https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/

Comment: @Metroids - I have, but it wasn't a hit. In fact, it was just my brain to complicate that case. You wouldn't believe it. But the solution was to separate first fragment into few more, and problem was solved - besides WHOLE css and html arrangement... So it was - FUN! But! The "Login" pop-up window does not show up still.